# htaccess rewrite not woking

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a htaccess file which should make pretty permalinks but when entering `example.com/file/test/something` it gets redirected to `example.com/some/path/file.php?parameter=test&something=something`

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule file/(.*)/(.*)$ /some/path/file.php?parameter=$1&something=$2
```

Why does this get redirected?

NOTE:
This only happens on my shared hosting server, on my localhost everything looks good.

Comment: Better to check with your host....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works absolutely fine. It seemed to be a temporary error at my hosters site. After waiting a day it worked again.